# Ansible playbook does not run tasks in roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a simple ansible roles with one task, but the problem is when i run it
the tasks are not actually started

It worked when I tried my task without roles and not sure why its happening when I try using roles.

Version of ansible: ansible 2.2.3.0

This is my run.yml

```
 - name: add user to general purpose
   hosts: localhosts
   roles:
    - adduser
```

cd adduser/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Create user
  shell: sudo adduser tom
```

Running

```
ansible-playbook run.yml -vvv
```

This is the output

```
 Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAYBOOK: run.yml 
**************************************************************
1 plays in run.yml

PLAY RECAP 
*********************************************************************
```

Comment: Have you tried to force manually a hosts list file? `ansible-playbook run.yml -k -i hostsfile`

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio thanks, it works with other hosts, it did work for localhosts as well when I pass -i hostsfile argument in the command

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a typo in your `hosts:` field; the name is `localhost` not `localhosts` (as there is no such thing as a plural of the local host)

---

Also, while this isn't what you asked, it is bad news to (a) manually use `sudo` in a module (b) call `adduser` unconditionally, as it will bomb the second time you run that playbook. The thing you want is to tell ansible that task needs elevated privileges and then make use of the [`user:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/user_module.html#user-module) module to allow ansible to *ensure* there is such a user by the end of that role:

```
- name: Create user
  become: yes
  user:
    name: tom
```

The benefit of being more declarative is (a) that's how ansible works (b) it allows ansible to be idempotent across runs